# Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem via the Jordan Curve Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

There is a  proof of the **Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem** 
via the **Jordan Curve Theorem** ?

**The Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem.** Let $B=\{x\in \mathbb R^2 :∥x∥≤1\}$  be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$  . Any continuous function $f:B\rightarrow B$  has a fixed point.

**The Jordan curve theorem.** The image of a
continuous injective mapping  $J:S^1\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ divides the plane into exactly two components, one of which is unbounded and
the other bounded. Moreover, both of these components have the image of the
mapping $J$ as their boundary.

[The Jordan Curve Theorem via the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/jordan/maehara.pdf)

$\partial B=S^{1}$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might enjoy David Gale's paper [The Game of Hex and the Brouwer Fixed-Point Theorem](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~gartside/hex_Browuer.pdf), The Monthly, Dec 1979,  pp. 818-827.  He gives direct proofs in both directions between the Brouwer Theorem and the:

**Hex Theorem:** The game of Hex cannot end in a tie.

As Gale explains, the Hex Theorem is completely elementary (Gale gives an algorithm that takes in a completed Hex board and finds a win for one of the two players).  But the Hex Theorem  can be thought of as a sort of "finite" or "discrete" version of the Jordan theorem (the weak form, needed for Brouwer, only says that at least one player wins; the strong form, that both cannot win, is closer to Jordan), and the former does follow from the latter (Beck, Bleicher, and Crow, *Excursion into Mathematics*, 1969, pp. 327-339).  For further discussion relationing the Hex and Jordan Theorems, see the three or so paragraphs after "Hex Theorem" in *op. cit.*, p. 820.

Comment: As a side-note: The Jan 2014 AMM has an article with the following abstract: "A short, inductive proof is presented of the fact that a Hex board cannot be colored such that winning conditions are satisfied for both players." Appropriately titled, the article has as its citation: Huneke, S. C. An Inductive Proof of Hex Uniqueness. *The American Mathematical Monthly, 121*(1), 78-80.